# Creating dynamic columns in an Ext JS Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am looking to create some logic for JSON data retrieved from a server request. As you can see from the raw data below, it is received in a particular format.

There is a **"balances"** entry which, in this case, has 5 different sub-values, of which names can vary dependent upon a given user.

For example:

---

- Barry has 5 bank accounts, each with **different** balances.
- Melissa has 2 bank accounts, each with **different** balances.
- Melissa's bank accounts are different to Barry's bank accounts, and vise versa.
- The Balance ID numbers that are assigned, may not necessarily match both Barry and Melissa.

---

In the Ext JS grid, the column headings which need to be displayed, must adjust to both Barry and Melissa's individual bank account balances.

**Barry's JSON Data:**

```
{
  "firstName": "Foo",
  "lastName": "Bar",
  "balances": 
  {
  Natwest: 9,
  BankofScotland: 2,
  Lloyds: 40,
  Halifax: 89,
  Lords: 12
  },
}
```

**Melissa's JSON Data:**

```
{
  "firstName": "Melissa",
  "lastName": "Bar",
  "balances": 
  {
  DifferentNatwest: 10,
  DiffferentBankofScotland: 45
  },
}
```

At the moment, I only have one mapping in my store/model, called "balances" which only takes one value:

**Store/Model definitions:**

```
fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'balances']
```

So, obviously the following issue occurs when the grid is generated, as more than one value is being passed:

**Results:**

[image: Grid]

**The Question:**

Does anyone know what I can do to get the columns to dynamically generate in this Ext JS grid, dependant upon the JSON data being received for this balances information?

Comment: Check this example, it could help you: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238780-Dynamic-fields-and-columns-in-a-grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is to create the grid columns and store for it dynamically.
I don't know if there is some more "ExtJS" way (simpler, automatic creation) but I would do a straightforward solution.

**1# Solution - with multiple columns**

- Get the data, get the JSON object
- Based on the JSON object create the new grid columns
- Based on the JSON object create the new store with correct records (I
  don't think there is model which can have object in it - you need to transofrm it)
- Create the grid and add the new store and columns to it.

Here is the code snippet with the most important part:

```
    for (var key in d.balances) {
        bankAcountsColumns.push({
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: key,
            text: key
        });

        transformData[key] = d.balances[key];
        fields.push(key);
    }

    var myCustomColumns = [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'firstName',
        text: 'Name'
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'lastName',
        text: 'LastName '
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Bank accounts',
        columns: bankAcountsColumns
    }]

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyGridPanel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        columns: myCustomColumns,
        store: {
            fields: fields,
            data: transformData
        }
    });
```

Here is working fiddle example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l5j

---

**2# Solution - one column**

If you want to have only one column with all the balances, you would need [`templatecolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Template)

In there I would create template for 5 items (or it can be again created dynamically):
`tpl:'{bank1name} {bank1value} {bank2name} {bank2value} ...'`

And than you would have to dynamically create the data for the new store.

```
data:[
    { firstName: "Foo", lastName:"Scott",   bank1name: "Natwest", bank1value: "9" ... },
    { firstname: "Dwight",  lastName: "Bar",  ... bank5name: "" ...  }    
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a fantastic answer  - I will take a look at the working example now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again @pagep, I am struggling to implement Solution #1 into a multi-class project. I have JSON data from my question above, which is sent to the account store, which then has a "config:" which links/uses an account model, where the ['firstName', 'lastName', 'balances'] fields are defined. I don't understand how to adapt the code you wrote in your Fiddle, relevant to this project setup? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have created a new question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805044/adapting-a-single-page-ext-js-application-to-mvc if interested. Thank you!

Comment: If you look at the fiddle `MyApp.store.MyStore` would be the same as your  account store. In your store you can use either fields or model / it doesn't matter. I think that you don't need to know about the model in your store unless you want to get some information from it. Hm according to your next Q you need more info that this small comment section can provide.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, but where does the: "Ext.application({  name: 'MyApp',    launch: function ()" section go, is that in the view?